# What exactly does the scale mean in geom_density?

Tags: ggplot2, kernel-density

What does "level" exactly mean when using geom_density_2d. I've really tried searching around but I can't find anything.

Every example I can see around has very small values, but when I try to make one with my data I get a max of 300, so I am very confused

Thanks

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/pdf-is-not-a-probability-5a4b8a5d9531

Comment: @CMichael thank you this is very helpful. I think I got very confused as I read someone's paper who did a PDF and referred to it as probability only.